# Null reference exception after instantiating a light gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, unityscript

I coded a class, where I declare a Light as an attribute. In the constructor I instantiate the Light object before using it, but I got the null reference exception at the line after the instantiation (`NodeLight.type = LightType.Spot;`).

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class Node{

     public bool walkable;
     public Vector3 worldPosition;
     public bool Selected;
     public Light NodeLight;

     public Node(bool _walkable, Vector3 _worldPos) {
         Selected = false;
         walkable = _walkable;
         worldPosition = _worldPos;
         NodeLight = new Light();
         NodeLight.type = LightType.Spot;
         NodeLight.transform.position = new Vector3(worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y + 3f, worldPosition.z);
         NodeLight.enabled = false;
     }
 }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which line throws the null reference exception? Have you tried using `Debug.Log()` to output values, to confirm they're as expected?

Comment: This is the line throwing the error: 
NodeLight.type = LightType.Spot;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Light` is a `Component`, so it should exist within a `GameObject`.

Have a look at this example from the [Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light.html):

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        GameObject lightGameObject = new GameObject("The Light");
        Light lightComp = lightGameObject.AddComponent<Light>();
        lightComp.color = Color.blue;
        lightGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
    }
}
```

Try this approach, or try adding your `NodeLight` as a `Component` of a `GameObject`, and then changing its position, rather than the individual `Light` component's.

Comment: Good catch! Always learning something new about Unity here. =D